# Typescript - infer constructor args to static factory method in parent class

Tags: typescript, generics

I have 1 base class called `Entity` and a sub-class `DebugEntity` which extends `Entity`. Child classes that derive from `Entity` can have their own constructor with arbitrary arguments. I want these arguments to be typed in the static `make` method that is inside the `Entity` class.

Afer a lot of trial/error, I got this far:

```js
class DebugEntity extends Entity
{
    public constructor(name: string, age: number)
    {
        console.log({name, age});
    }

    public testMe(): void
    {
        console.log('Hello from DebugEntity')
    }

}
```

```js
export abstract class Entity
{
    public static async make<T extends Entity, K extends new (...args: any[]) => T>(
        this: K,
        ...args: K extends new (...args: infer U) => T ? U : never
    ): Promise<T>
    {
        const entity     = new this(...args);
        
        // Do some async stuff (unrelated to question)

        return entity;
    }
}
```

Typescript infers the constructor parameters correctly. E.g.: `DebugEntity.make()` now expects two parameters `[string, number]`. However, Typescript thinks the return type of `make` is of type `Entity` instead of `DebugEntity`.

Calling `testMe` on the constructed entity results in the following:

> `Property 'testMe' does not exist on type 'Entity'.`

I can fix this easily by modifying the `this:` argument to `this: new (...args: any[]) => T`, but for some reason this breaks the argument type inferring.

How should I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I did some more funky trial and error right after posting, and apparently this works:

```js
    public static async make<T extends Entity, K extends new (...args: any[]) => InstanceType<K>>(
        this: K,
        ...args: K extends new (...args: infer U) => T ? U : never
    ): Promise<InstanceType<K>>
    {
        const entity     = new this(...args);

        // do async stuff.

        return entity;
    }
```

The use of the built-in `InstanceType` type did the trick.
I am unsure of any unwanted side-effects though...

Comment: This is a really nice solution! I tried using `InstanceType<typeof this>` and unexpectedly that did not work. It seems that the important part that worked is your use of the first argument `this: K`. It is truly strange that `typeof this` does not achieve the same result.

Comment: To give some more background, I was trying to call the parent class', say `Parent` static method from a child class, say `Child.parentStaticMethod()`, but when using `typeof this`, Typescript always thinks that the `this` binding has type `typeof Parent`. Now that I add the first pseudoargument of `this: K`, Typescript correctly infers the `this` type to be `typeof Child`.

Comment: Nice work. Exactly what I needed!